# I want file names in array as in windows folder order by name. so what to do?

Tags: php

In windows when we see detail view of folder and order by name i want exactly that sequence

in windows i get LEU2G0014L1A01.pdf as first in order but by my code i get LEU2G001041B01.pdf first in array any solution.?

```
<?php

$dir = "A/";
$result =   find_all_files($dir);


sort($result);
print_r($result);

function find_all_files($dir) 
{ 
$root = scandir($dir); 
  foreach($root as $value) 
  { 
      if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 

        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$value";continue;} 
          foreach(find_all_files("$dir/$value") as $value) 
          { 
             $result[]=$value; 

          } 

  } 

return $result; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: What do you mean with "as in windows". Default sorting for scandir is alfabetical, which would be the same in Widows, afaik

Answer (score 2):

you're probably looking for natural sort http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example obtained from php manual site:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
<?php
$dir = "/tmp";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

sort($files);
print_r($files);
rsort($files);
print_r($files);
?>
```

Produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
Array
(
    [0] => somedir
    [1] => foo.txt
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
```